# Apple Macbook Moving Desktop Files, Folders, Icons

Tags: macos, folders

When I go to organize my desktop by moving multiple Files, Folders, or Icons at the same time it groups them all together. How to I prevent it from doing this?

Thank you.

(System - Macbook Pro OS 10.9.5)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you are dragging them there is no way to disable this, with the exception that if you perform this action in Finder list view it would show a list of the folders instead of large icons. The intention is that you need to be able to see your drag target, so it tidies them into a bundle.